# .htaccess for domain change with subdomains - apache + plesk

Tags: apache, .htaccess, plesk

We're using a plesk based system and just recently changed domain names.  I'd like to redirect all requests coming in to the old domain to the new.  There are many question asked in a similar fashion but mine is a bit different.  I'd like to ensure that all subdomains get routed to the same subdoamin on the new domain.   I set up a generic htaccess in the docroot but for some reason it is also applying to all subdomains.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

How can I make this more general so that subdomains also appropriately get routed?  For bonus points, how can I route https requests to https and http to http.

I'd like to add that the rule transforms the first url to the second which is not desirable:

```
http://SUBDOMAIN.olddomain.com/somepath/somefile.php
http://newdomain.com/subdomains/SUBDOMAIN/httpdocs/somepath/somefile.php
```

The proper transform should create the following url:

```
http://SUBDOMAIN.newdomain.com/somepath/somefile.php
```

Lastly, this should work with wildcard subdomains.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# ignore "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.olddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You'd want this **before** the rule that you already have.

And since you've edited your question, you want an additional internal rewrite for handling subdomains in general on your new site, this has nothing to do with the redirect. This is brand new functionality that is outside of the scope of a 301 redirect. You're going to need special rules to handle internal routing of subdomains:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomains/%1/httpdocs/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I apologize for the confusion.  I clarified the desirable redirect path above.  Basically I want to create the following url http://SUBDOMAIN.newdomain.com/somepath/somefile.php and also have it work with wildcard subdomains.

Comment: @VinnyD You are asking for 2 completely different things here